# I use CCTextFieldTTF and call method attachWithIME() but even can't Open keyboard on pad

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

——1、I create cclayer's subClass:

```
class LogoInLayer : public cocos2d::CCLayer
{

public:

    void onEnter();
    void onExit();
    void registerWithTouchDispatcher();
    bool ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* pTouch, CCEvent* event);
    void ccTouchEnded(CCTouch* pTouch, CCEvent* event);
    void ccTouchMoved(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
    void keyMenuClicked();
    void keyBackClicked();

};
```

——2、In onEnter method,I created a CCTextFieldTTF pointer and set:

```
CCTextFieldTTF * l = CCTextFieldTTF::textFieldWithPlaceHolder("12345567", "", 25);

l->setPosition(ccp(200,200));

addChild(l, 5,1234);

    this->setIsTouchEnabled(true);
    this->setIsKeypadEnabled(true);
```

——3、And also override registerWithTouchDispatcher() method:

```
void LogoInLayer::registerWithTouchDispatcher()
{

    CCTouchDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()
      ->addTargetedDelegate(this, kCCMenuTouchPriority + 2, true);

}
```

——4、Then I write code In CCTouchBegan:

```
CCTextFieldTTF* l = (CCTextFieldTTF*)this->getChildByTag(1234);

l->attachWithIME();
```

I couldn't find anything wrong,but even can't Open keyboard on pad when running.

Comment: Since this is C++ code I'm assuming you're using cocos2d-x, I changed the tag accordingly. It's difficult to understand what you're asking here. Is the CCTouchBegan method called? Did you add a breakpoint there to verify?